# How to save video using mediastore api in Android Q and above? (Video is in Internal/External Storage)

Tags: android

After the restrictions introduced in Android 10 and 11, I am finding it difficult to fetch a video in Internal / External Storage and copy into app specific directory, then use it(Permission Denied Error is thrown). For the image, I implemented the below:

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
Bitmap bm = testObj.getScaledBitmap(bitmap);//used own method
Uri uriimg = testObj.storeImage(internalPath + imageName, bm);//used own method
```

I am unable to do the same for video.
Could you please provide the code for fetching video using Mediastore api and store in app specific directory or provide mediastore api video fetch example?
I also appreciate very much if i can get scopedstorage usage example using JAVA, because most examples i found are using Kotlin only.

Code:
After file picked on activity result, then check if its video, then

```
File file = new File(getPath(ProductFlipperActivity.this,uri));
```

getPath method:

```
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
    Log.i("URI", uri + "");
    String result = uri + "";
    // DocumentProvider
    //  if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
    if (isKitKat && (result.contains("media.documents"))) {
        String[] ary = result.split("/");
        int length = ary.length;
        String imgary = ary[length - 1];
        final String[] dat = imgary.split("%3A");
        final String docId = dat[1];
        final String type = dat[0];
        Uri contentUri = null;
        if ("image".equals(type)) {
            contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
            contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
            contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        }
        final String selection = "_id=?";
        final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                dat[1]
        };
        return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
    } else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }
    return null;
}
```

getDataColumn method():

```
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };
    try {
        if (checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(context)) {
            // do your stuff..

            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Get the file name and use storepdf method

```
String videoName = file.getName();
testObj.storePDF(internalPath + videoName, file);
```

storepdf method to save file in app specific directory:

```
//store pdf to sdcard
public Uri storePDF(String path, File file) {
    Uri uri = null;
    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
        String newFileName = path;
        out = new FileOutputStream(newFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }
    return Uri.fromFile(file);
}
```

After using uri to save file and when i open inputstream to the real file path or uri, both throw error:

```
File file = new File(String.valueOf(uri));
//File file = new File(getPath(ProductFlipperActivity.this,uri));
String videoName = file.getName();
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(internalPath + videoName));
// Copy the bits from instream to outstream
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int len;

while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
    out.write(buf, 0, len);
}

in.close();
out.close();
```

Error Resolved by using the following code suggested by @blackapps:

```
File file = new File(getPath(ProductFlipperActivity.this,uri));
String videoName = file.getName();
InputStream in = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
OutputStream out = this.getContentResolver().openOutputStream((Uri.fromFile(new File(internalPath + videoName))));
// Copy the bits from instream to outstream
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read;
while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
in.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: `(Video is in Internal/External Storage)` Well.. then why would you make a copy if the video is already on your device?

Comment: the user picks video from his internal/external storage, and it needs to be copied to app specific directory for further use.. ie. inside data/data/com.myapp/folder/ ... but it throws permission denied in android 10 and 11 @blackapps

Comment: I see no code. So why dont you post your code to begin with? And we have no idea for what or when you would see a permission denied. Start posting code for 'the user picks'.

Comment: yes @blackapps..  i will post now.. thanks

Comment: @blackapps I updated the code.. it works fine till Android 9..

Comment: That looks like pretty bad code whete you try to get a path for an uri. Dont do such things. You can easier copy from an uri. Moreover you did not start with the intent to pick a file. And what has storePdf() to do with a video file?

Comment: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) - error thrown.. this code was developed many years ago, i am just trying to fix this particular video upload bug for android 10 and 11.. and storePdf() is common method they used for both pdf and video upload

Comment: That code makes no sense and i told you why. Use the uri. Dont try to get a path from it.

Comment: ok.. I will try copying the file using uri.. But direct storage access is restricted in Android 10 and 11 right? @blackapps

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Or what this has to do with a simple copy of a file which can be done in less than ten code lines. Sorry.

Comment: @blackapps While using uri, I am getting error, file not found content:/com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A2897: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory), Can you please give me sample code which i can use, please?

Comment: @blackapps I tried using ParcelableFileDescriptor to do the copy, but same error is being thrown

Comment: Post your code in your post. Make a new code block to begin with. Just open an input stream for the uri.

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: content:/com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A2897: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: @blackapps I updated the code in question.. its still throws the error when i try opening an inputstream for that file

Comment: `File file = new File(String.valueOf(uri));` That is nonsense. Dont use the File class for an uri. Open an InputStream for the uri directly and use it as if it was your FileInputStream.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks a lot for your help.. The error is now resolved and its working perfect..  InputStream in = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);                            OutputStream out = this.getContentResolver().openOutputStream((Uri.fromFile(new File(internalPath + videoName)))); I will check once in Android 11 too.. Thanks again..

Comment: @commonsware Thanks a lot for this article - https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html